# Spark transforme foreach into map

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

In spark streaming I have the following problem.

```
                       [Map A] - [Foreach to cassandra]
                      /                  
[Kafka Input stream] <
                      \
                       [Map B] - [Foreach to cassandra]
```

But I have to commit the offsets at the end of this stream.

What I do now, it's to add another fork: 
`[Kafka Input stream] - [Foreach offset to kafka manager]`

But of course it works when spark is totally stopped but if Map A fails ( exemple cassandra overload ) offsets are still committed to the offset manager.

The right things to do is

```
                       [Map A] - [Map to cassandra]
                      /                            \
[Kafka Input stream] <                              > [Foreach to offset manager]
                      \                            /
                       [Map B] - [Map to cassandra]
```

But the [Foreach cassandra] is part of cassandra spark connector and it's not my code, so I'm stuck with a foreach.
And I don't want to rewrite cassandra spark connector because I think they have done a great job.

So the question is : is there a way to use these foreach and being notified if they fail of not, to know if I have to commit my offsets or not?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: which part ?
Libs specific code? ( cassandra and kafka ?) or piping code ?